# R: Boxplot - how to move the x-axis label down?

Tags: r, statistics, axis-labels

```
#RGR ~ Treatment:Geno boxplot
fit <- aov(Total.RGR~Treatment:Geno, data=For.R)
summary(fit)
t <- TukeyHSD(fit)
t
boxplot(Total.RGR~Treatment:Geno, 
data=For.R,las=2,ylim=c(-20,100),xlab="Treatment:Geno",ylab="RGR (mg/day)")
text(1:8, 95 ,c("a","ac","a","a","a","bd","bcd","ad"))
```

Is my code, it does the job, but when I rotate my x-axis labels the obstruct the x-axis title.
Does any of you know of a way to move the title down?

[image]

It must be easy but I cant find anything in the reference.

Thanks.
Mathias

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would set `xlab=""` and add it afterwards using `mtext`. So, either you play with `line` parameter an put it the bottom under your lables Or change completely the side to put it in the top of the plot.

```
   mtext("Treatment:Geno", side=1, line=5)
   mtext("Treatment:Geno", side=3)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. It seems so easy now, I like R, but i find that figuring out simple stuff can be so hard.