# Replace x-axis with label as weekdays

Tags: r, plot, label, axis

I have made a plot :

```
plot(tapply(G$capacity, G$day, mean),type="b", ylim=c(250,400), 
     xlim=c(0,7),main="Capacity ",xaxt = "n",  xlab="weekday", ylab ="Capacity")
```

and I would like to label the scale with Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday, etc.. and not with numbers.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 3):

Try adding the argument `xaxt="n"` to your `plot command` and subsequently:

```
 wd <- weekdays(Sys.Date()+2:8)
 axis(1, at=seq_along(wd), labels=wd, las=2)
```

If you really want the x-axis label 'weekday', you can prevent clashing by setting xlab="" in your `plot` and setting the label manually with `mtext` (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26180178/r-boxplot-how-to-move-the-x-axis-label-down))