# Adjust distance from xlab to x-axis

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart

I wanted to move the xlab "Treatment" down so that it doesn't overlap the treatment names. I referred to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26180178/r-boxplot-how-to-move-the-x-axis-label-down) but couldn't solve the problem.

This is the data

```html
         Date Plot  Rep Side    Crop  Rot Rot.Herb Rot.trt Herb.trt
    1   8-Sep-14   11 1rep    W    corn 3rot   C3conv      C3     conv
    2   8-Sep-14   11 1rep    E    corn 3rot    C3low      C3      low
    3   8-Sep-14   13 1rep    W    corn 2rot    C2low      C2      low
    4   8-Sep-14   13 1rep    E    corn 2rot   C2conv      C2     conv
    5   8-Sep-14   18 1rep    W    corn 4rot    C4low      C4      low
    6   8-Sep-14   18 1rep    E    corn 4rot   C4conv      C4     conv
    7  10-Sep-14   23 2rep    W    corn 3rot   C3conv      C3     conv
    8  10-Sep-14   23 2rep    E    corn 3rot    C3low      C3      low
    9  10-Sep-14   24 2rep    W    corn 2rot    C2low      C2      low
    10 10-Sep-14   24 2rep    E    corn 2rot   C2conv      C2     conv
    11 10-Sep-14   28 2rep    W    corn 4rot   C4conv      C4     conv
    12 10-Sep-14   28 2rep    E    corn 4rot    C4low      C4      low
    13 10-Sep-14   34 3rep    W    corn 2rot    C2low      C2      low
    14 10-Sep-14   34 3rep    E    corn 2rot   C2conv      C2     conv
    15 10-Sep-14   37 3rep    W    corn 4rot    C4low      C4      low
    16 10-Sep-14   37 3rep    E    corn 4rot   C4conv      C4     conv
    17 10-Sep-14   38 3rep    W    corn 3rot   C3conv      C3     conv
    18 10-Sep-14   38 3rep    E    corn 3rot    C3low      C3      low
    19 12-Sep-14   44 4rep    W    corn 2rot   C2conv      C2     conv
    20 12-Sep-14   44 4rep    E    corn 2rot    C2low      C2      low
    21 12-Sep-14   46 4rep    W    corn 4rot    C4low      C4      low
    22 12-Sep-14   46 4rep    E    corn 4rot   C4conv      C4     conv
    23 12-Sep-14   48 4rep    W    corn 3rot    C3low      C3      low
    24 13-Sep-14   48 4rep    E    corn 3rot   C3conv      C3     conv
    25 15-Sep-14   14 1rep    W soybean 4rot    S4low      S4      low
    26 15-Sep-14   14 1rep    E soybean 4rot   S4conv      S4     conv
    27 15-Sep-14   16 1rep    W soybean 3rot   S3conv      S3     conv
    28 15-Sep-14   16 1rep    E soybean 3rot    S3low      S3      low
    29 15-Sep-14   19 1rep    W soybean 2rot    S2low      S2      low
    30 15-Sep-14   19 1rep    E soybean 2rot   S2conv      S2     conv
    31 15-Sep-14   25 2rep    W soybean 3rot    S3low      S3      low
    32 15-Sep-14   25 2rep    E soybean 3rot   S3conv      S3     conv
    33 15-Sep-14   27 2rep    W soybean 2rot   S2conv      S2     conv
    34 15-Sep-14   27 2rep    E soybean 2rot    S2low      S2      low
    35 15-Sep-14   29 2rep    W soybean 4rot   S4conv      S4     conv
    36 15-Sep-14   29 2rep    E soybean 4rot    S4low      S4      low
       DIGSANo DIGSAWt SETFANo SETFAWt SETLUNo SETLUWt PANCANo PANCAWt
    1       NA      NA       1    0.10      NA      NA      NA      NA
    2       NA      NA       3   61.00      NA      NA      NA      NA
    3       NA      NA       1    1.50      NA      NA      NA      NA
    4       NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA
    5        2    1.30       2   14.00       1    0.10      NA      NA
    6       NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA
    7       NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA
    8       NA      NA       2    4.10      NA      NA      NA      NA
    9       NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA
    10      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA
    11       2    0.25      NA      NA       7    7.00      NA      NA
    12      NA      NA      15   31.40       1    0.06      NA      NA
    13      NA      NA       2    1.45      NA      NA      NA      NA
    14      NA      NA       1    0.15      NA      NA      NA      NA
    15      NA      NA       1    0.07      NA      NA      NA      NA
    16      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA
    17      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA
    18       1    0.90       2    9.10      NA      NA      NA      NA
    19      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA
    20      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA
    21       4    3.97       6   71.50       3    3.09      NA      NA
    22      NA      NA       1    2.31       2    0.26      NA      NA
    23      NA      NA       6    8.90     382  160.30      NA      NA
    24      NA      NA      NA      NA     226  101.60      NA      NA
    25       1    0.14       5   10.60      NA      NA      NA      NA
    26      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA
    27      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA
    28      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA
    29       1    2.99      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA
    30      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA
    31      NA      NA       2   40.50      NA      NA      NA      NA
    32      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA
    33      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA
    34      NA      NA       2    3.02      NA      NA       2    4.39
    35      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA
    36      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA
       ECHCGNo ECHCGWt ERBVINo ERBVIWt CYPESNo CYPESWt AMATANo AMATAWt
    1       NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA
    2       NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA       2   25.50
    3       NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA       8    8.30
    4       NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA       4    0.10
    5        6   21.70      NA      NA      NA      NA       2    1.20
    6       NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA       1    0.00
    7       NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA       1    0.00
    8       NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA
    9       NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA       1    0.03
    10      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA       3    1.57
    11      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA       2    0.01
    12      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      11    5.30
    13      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA       3    0.03
    14      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA       1    0.03
    15      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA
    16      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA
    17      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA       1    0.00
    18      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA
    19      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA       1    0.06
    20      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      11   34.50
    21      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA
    22      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA
    23      NA      NA       6    42.5      NA      NA      32   26.10
    24      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA       2    0.00
    25      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA       9   82.00
    26      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA       2    1.55
    27      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA       3    2.92
    28      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      23   66.10
    29      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA       4   15.07
    30      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA       3    1.79
    31      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      53  235.10
    32      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA       2    0.08
    33      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA       5    0.38
    34       1   14.72       2    32.4      NA      NA      20   99.10
    35      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA
    36      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      10  112.30
       CHEALNo CHEALWt SOLPTNo SOLPTWt PHYSUNo PHYSUWt POLCCNo POLCCWt
    1        6    0.10      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA
    2       44  208.10      NA      NA       5    2.10      NA      NA
    3       NA      NA      NA      NA       2   13.90      NA      NA
    4       NA      NA      NA      NA       6    0.00      NA      NA
    5       NA      NA      NA      NA       2    0.10      NA      NA
    6       NA      NA      11    0.40       1    0.00      NA      NA
    7       NA      NA       1    0.08      NA      NA      NA      NA
    8       15   41.80       3    0.30      NA      NA      NA      NA
    9        2    0.20      18    5.81      NA      NA      NA      NA
    10      NA      NA       4    0.17      NA      NA      NA      NA
    11      NA      NA       5    0.95      NA      NA      NA      NA
    12      NA      NA       7    1.04      NA      NA      NA      NA
    13      NA      NA       2    0.20       2    3.06      NA      NA
    14      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA
    15       2    4.55       4    0.85       2    0.06      NA      NA
    16      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA
    17       1    0.00       2    0.30      NA      NA      NA      NA
    18       8   26.30       1    0.05      NA      NA      NA      NA
    19      NA      NA      NA      NA      11    0.24      NA      NA
    20       1   49.40      NA      NA       2    0.33      NA      NA
    21      NA      NA      NA      NA       3    0.32      NA      NA
    22      NA      NA      NA      NA       3    2.06      NA      NA
    23       1      NA      NA      NA       6    0.35      NA      NA
    24      NA      NA      NA      NA       1    0.04      NA      NA
    25       5    8.00      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA
    26       1    0.08      NA      NA       1    0.03      NA      NA
    27       4    0.34       1    0.10      NA      NA      NA      NA
    28      86  262.10      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA
    29       3    8.06      NA      NA       2    1.08      NA      NA
    30      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA
    31      41  133.10       2    1.47      NA      NA      NA      NA
    32      15    1.01       1    0.06      NA      NA      NA      NA
    33       1    0.03       1    0.00       1    0.00      NA      NA
    34       3    4.57       2    0.37      NA      NA      NA      NA
    35      NA      NA       1    0.09      NA      NA      NA      NA
    36      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA
       POLPYNo POLPYWt ABUTHNo ABUTHWt TAROFNo TAROFWt EPHHTNo EPHHTWt
    1       NA      NA       4    0.20       6    0.10      NA      NA
    2       NA      NA      NA      NA       4    0.00      NA      NA
    3       NA      NA       2    0.10      NA      NA      NA      NA
    4       NA      NA      NA      NA      21    0.00       1    0.00
    5       NA      NA       6    3.10       6    0.10       2    0.10
    6       NA      NA      NA      NA       3    0.00      NA      NA
    7       NA      NA       1    0.07       6    0.07      NA      NA
    8       NA      NA      NA      NA       7    0.23      NA      NA
    9       NA      NA      NA      NA      17    0.18       5    0.13
    10      NA      NA      NA      NA      33    0.51      NA      NA
    11      NA      NA       4    0.66       5    0.06       2    0.04
    12      NA      NA      NA      NA       3    0.10       1    0.08
    13      NA      NA      NA      NA       7    0.20      NA      NA
    14      NA      NA      NA      NA      17    0.24      NA      NA
    15       1    0.41       4    9.50      14    0.57      36    0.66
    16      NA      NA      NA      NA      11    0.18      13    0.31
    17      NA      NA       3    0.09       9    0.13      NA      NA
    18      NA      NA       1    0.05      31    2.60      NA      NA
    19      NA      NA      NA      NA       8    0.03      NA      NA
    20       2    0.72      NA      NA       6    0.09      NA      NA
    21      NA      NA      18   40.40       2    0.02       2    0.03
    22      NA      NA      NA      NA       3    0.02      NA      NA
    23      NA      NA       4    1.47       9    0.13      NA      NA
    24      NA      NA      NA      NA       5    0.00      NA      NA
    25      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA
    26      NA      NA      NA      NA       1    0.00      NA      NA
    27      NA      NA       2    0.69       1    0.00      NA      NA
    28      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA
    29      NA      NA       1    2.72       1    0.24      NA      NA
    30      NA      NA      NA      NA      40    1.65      NA      NA
    31      NA      NA       1    0.04      NA      NA      NA      NA
    32      NA      NA      NA      NA       1    0.00      NA      NA
    33       3    0.21      NA      NA       1    0.00      NA      NA
    34      NA      NA      NA      NA       1    0.05      NA      NA
    35      NA      NA       2    1.63       1    0.00      NA      NA
    36      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA
       CIRARNo CIRARWt SONARNo SONARWt MORALNo MORALWt OXASTNo OXASTWt
    1       NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA
    2       NA      NA      NA      NA       5    0.00      NA      NA
    3       NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA
    4       NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA
    5       NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA
    6       NA      NA      NA      NA       1    0.00      NA      NA
    7       NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA
    8       NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA
    9       NA      NA       1    0.10      NA      NA      NA      NA
    10      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA
    11      NA      NA       1    0.02      NA      NA      NA      NA
    12      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA       1    0.14
    13      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA
    14      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA
    15      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA
    16      NA      NA       1    0.01       1    0.02       1    0.00
    17      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA
    18      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA
    19      NA      NA      NA      NA       6    0.10      NA      NA
    20      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA
    21      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA
    22      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA
    23      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA
    24      NA      NA      NA      NA       1    0.03      NA      NA
    25      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA
    26      NA      NA      NA      NA       1    0.08      NA      NA
    27      NA      NA      NA      NA       1    0.00      NA      NA
    28      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA
    29      NA      NA      NA      NA       1    0.05      NA      NA
    30      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA
    31      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA
    32      NA      NA      NA      NA       1    0.00      NA      NA
    33      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA
    34      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA
    35      NA      NA      NA      NA       1    0.00      NA      NA
    36      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA
       POLLANo POLLAWt ASCSYNo ASCSYWt POLAVNo POLAVWt PLAMANo PLAMAWt
    1       NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA
    2       NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA
    3       NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA
    4       NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA
    5       NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA
    6       NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA
    7       NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA
    8       NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA
    9       NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA
    10      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA
    11      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA
    12       4     2.6      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA
    13      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA
    14      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA
    15      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA
    16      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA
    17      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA
    18      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA
    19      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA
    20      NA      NA       1    0.04      NA      NA      NA      NA
    21      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA
    22      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA
    23      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA
    24      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA
    25      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA
    26      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA
    27      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA
    28      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA
    29      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA
    30      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA
    31      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA
    32      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA
    33      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA
    34      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA
    35      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA
    36      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA
       UnknowndicotNo UnknowndicotWt UnknownmonocotNo UnknownmonocotWt
    1              NA             NA               NA               NA
    2              NA             NA               NA               NA
    3              NA             NA               NA               NA
    4              NA             NA               NA               NA
    5              NA             NA               NA               NA
    6              NA             NA               NA               NA
    7              NA             NA               NA               NA
    8              NA             NA               NA               NA
    9              NA             NA               NA               NA
    10             NA             NA               NA               NA
    11             NA             NA               NA               NA
    12             NA             NA               NA               NA
    13             NA             NA               NA               NA
    14             NA             NA               NA               NA
    15             NA             NA               NA               NA
    16             NA             NA               NA               NA
    17             NA             NA               NA               NA
    18             NA             NA               NA               NA
    19             NA             NA               NA               NA
    20             NA             NA               NA               NA
    21             NA             NA               NA               NA
    22             NA             NA               NA               NA
    23              2           2.19                1             0.03
    24             NA             NA               NA               NA
    25              1             NA               NA               NA
    26              1           0.04               NA               NA
    27             NA             NA               NA               NA
    28             NA             NA               NA               NA
    29             NA             NA               NA               NA
    30             NA             NA               NA               NA
    31             NA             NA               NA               NA
    32              1           0.00               NA               NA
    33             NA             NA               NA               NA
    34             NA             NA               NA               NA
    35             NA             NA               NA               NA
    36             NA             NA               NA               NA
       TOTALNo TOTALWt samplearea.m.2. g.m.2  kg.ha lb.acre
    1       17    0.50          18.532  0.03   0.27    0.24
    2       63  296.70          18.532 16.01 160.10  142.97
    3       13   23.80          18.532  1.28  12.84   11.47
    4       32    0.10          18.532  0.01   0.05    0.05
    5       29   41.70          18.532  2.25  22.50   20.09
    6       17    0.40          18.532  0.02   0.22    0.19
    7        9    0.22          18.532  0.01   0.12    0.11
    8       27   46.43          18.532  2.51  25.05   22.37
    9       44    6.45          18.532  0.35   3.48    3.11
    10      40    2.25          18.532  0.12   1.21    1.08
    11      28    8.99          18.532  0.49   4.85    4.33
    12      43   40.72          18.532  2.20  21.97   19.62
    13      16    4.94          18.532  0.27   2.67    2.38
    14      19    0.42          18.532  0.02   0.23    0.20
    15      64   16.67          18.532  0.90   9.00    8.03
    16      27    0.52          18.532  0.03   0.28    0.25
    17      16    0.52          18.532  0.03   0.28    0.25
    18      44   39.00          18.532  2.10  21.04   18.79
    19      26    0.43          18.532  0.02   0.23    0.21
    20      23   85.08          18.532  4.59  45.91   41.00
    21      38  119.33          18.532  6.44  64.39   57.50
    22       9    4.65          18.532  0.25   2.51    2.24
    23     449  241.97          18.532 13.06 130.57  116.60
    24     235  101.67          18.532  5.49  54.86   48.99
    25      21  100.74          18.532  5.44  54.36   48.54
    26       7    1.78          18.532  0.10   0.96    0.86
    27      12    4.05          18.532  0.22   2.19    1.95
    28     109  328.20          18.532 17.71 177.10  158.15
    29      13   30.21          18.532  1.63  16.30   14.56
    30      43    3.44          18.532  0.19   1.86    1.66
    31      99  410.21          18.532 22.14 221.35  197.67
    32      21    1.15          18.532  0.06   0.62    0.55
    33      12    0.62          18.532  0.03   0.33    0.30
    34      33  158.62          18.532  8.56  85.59   76.43
    35       5    1.72          18.532  0.09   0.93    0.83
    36      10  112.30          18.532  6.06  60.60   54.11
```

Here is the code which produce the following graph

```html
weedweights<-weeds%>%
  select(-ends_with("No"))%>%
  gather(key=species, value=speciesmass, DIGSAWt:UnknownmonocotWt)%>%
  mutate(realmass=speciesmass * samplearea.m.2.)%>%
  group_by(Rot.Herb, species)%>%
  summarize(avgrealmass=mean(realmass, na.rm=TRUE))%>%
  filter(avgrealmass != "NaN")%>%
  arrange(-avgrealmass) %>% 
  ungroup() %>%
  mutate(species = gsub("Wt$", "", species))

ggplot(weedweights, aes(x=Rot.Herb, y=avgrealmass, fill=species))+
  geom_bar(stat="identity")+
  theme_bw()+
  theme(panel.grid.major=element_blank())+
  scale_fill_manual(values=c("red","burlywood4","olivedrab","orange","chocolate","azure4","cornflowerblue","maroon","cyan","lightblue","blueviolet","darkgoldenrod","darkgrey","darkmagenta","dodgerblue","gold","darkslateblue","darksalmon","greenyellow","deeppink","brown1","cornsilk","orchid","black","pink2"),
                    name="Species")+
  ggtitle("Weed biomass by treatment")+
  theme(plot.title = element_text(size=16, face="bold", vjust=2))+
  xlab("Treatment")+
  theme(axis.title = element_text(face="bold", vjust=4))+
  ylab="Total weed biomass (kg per ha)"+
  theme(axis.title = element_text(face="bold", vjust=2))
```

graph
[image]

and here is the modified code that I tried which did not move the xlab

```html
ggplot(weedweights, aes(x=Rot.Herb, y=avgrealmass, fill=species))+
  geom_bar(stat="identity")+
  theme_bw()+
  theme(panel.grid.major=element_blank())+
  scale_fill_manual(values=c("red","burlywood4","olivedrab","orange","chocolate","azure4","cornflowerblue","maroon","cyan","lightblue","blueviolet","darkgoldenrod","darkgrey","darkmagenta","dodgerblue","gold","darkslateblue","darksalmon","greenyellow","deeppink","brown1","cornsilk","orchid","black","pink2"),
                    name="Species")+
  ggtitle("Weed biomass by treatment")+
  theme(plot.title = element_text(size=16, face="bold", vjust=2))+
  xlab("Treatment")+
  mtext("Treatment", side=1, line=5)+
  theme(axis.title = element_text(face="bold", vjust=4))+
  ylab="Total weed biomass (kg per ha)"+
  theme(axis.title = element_text(face="bold", vjust=2))
```

Comment: Have a look at `?theme`; in particular, look at theme elements: `axis.title`, `axis.title.x`, and `axis.title.y`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `atop` to move it down a line by putting it below a line containing nothing.

```
xlab(expression(atop("","Treatment")))
```

Or you can use `\n` to insert a newline or two before the label.

```
xlab("\n\nTreatment")
```

`mtext` doesn't work with `ggplot2` as far as I can see. Or use `annotate` as seen [here](http://docs.ggplot2.org/current/geom_text.html) to place the text where you need it and `xlab("")` to omit the default label.

Comment: Thanks so much! The `"\n\nTreatment"` is the most convenient